# Убрать пробелы и добавить тире после слова

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью регулярки сделать из этого `CA - Los Angeles` вот это `CA-Los-Angeles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'CA - Los Angeles'.replace(/(\s?-\s?)|\s/g, '-')
```

Разберем регулярку `(\s*-\s*)|\s`, cостоящую из 2х частей:

1. (\s*-\s*) -> заменит части по типу **с-с**, **c -c,** **c- c** (учитывает возможное отсутствие пробела до\после тире) на тире
2. \s заменит просто пробелы на тире

Comment: Cпасибо, помог)

Comment: Я бы заменил `\s?` на `\s*`

Comment: @АлександрСтупак, не забудьте принять ответ зелёной галкой.

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо. согласен

Comment: @АлександрСтупак, отметите ответ, как правильный ?

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov да, конечно, спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

```
'CA - Los Angeles'.replace(/\s/g, '-').replace(/-{2}/g, '')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает с 'CA- Los Angeles' (нет пробела перед тире)

Comment: Сразу не увидел :) Мой недочёт, не предусмотрел